# Cannot get locationInView: for this type of NSTouch assertion error when trying to retrieve location

Tags: swift, macos, scenekit, macbookpro-touch-bar

I'm trying to retrieve the mouse location after a user clicks on a specific SCNNode.  I eventually want to perform a hit test to determine which SCNNode was clicked.  I have the following code but once I run the project I get an assertion error stating: "Cannot get locationInView: for this type of NSTouch".  Any help would be appreciated.

```
override func touchesBegan(with event: NSEvent) {
    let touch = event.touches(for: self.view)
    if #available(OSX 10.12.2, *) {
        let location = touch.first?.location(in: self.view)
        let hitResults = sceneView.hitTest(location!, options: nil)

    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
}
```

Comment: Lack of relevent tags

Comment: Find out what NSTouch really does before using it.  What you should use is probably the mouseDown event.

Answer (score 0):

[`-locationInView:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstouch/2588250-locationinview?language=objc) will only work for touches of [`type`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstouch/2544708-type?language=objc) [`NSTouchTypeDirect`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstouchtype/nstouchtypedirect?language=objc). If you have a Mac with a Touch Bar, pressing it will lead to an event with a touch of type [`NSTouchTypeIndirect`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstouchtype/nstouchtypeindirect?language=objc) which has no location on the screen.