# How can I convert NSTouch coordinates to screen coordinates?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstouch

In Cocoa on macOS, the `NSTouch` object contains the coordinates of a touch in a normalized coordinate system (with x, y in the range between 0.0 and 1.0). And it also has the size of the touchpad device.

So for an `NSTouch` object you have to coordinates of the touch on the touchpad device. This makes of course much sense.

What I am now trying to do is to map these coordinates to screen coordinates. (I know that this is not well-defined, so please read on for a further explanation what I mean by that.)

For a single-touch, this conversion is handled already by Cocoa/macOS: I get an `NSEvent` object (`type=Gesture`) and this `NSEvent` has the location of the mouse pointer (and the single `NSTouch` of the `NSEvent` has the touchpad-device coordinates).

But this does not work for a multi-touch gesture since the `NSEvent` has only one location and for multi-touch gestures, the location of the mouse pointer stays at the position where the multi-touch gesture started.

This makes all very much sense. But now I want somehow to do the same transformation that is done for the single-touch case (for each of the touches in the multi-touch gesture). I believe that the trackpad speed settings in the system preferences will influence such a mapping.

If you are wondering about a use-case, think of a drawing app that would allow multi-line (multi-touch) drawings and those multi-line drawings should happen with the same speed as the mouse pointer.

I found that `NSTouch` has a `locationInView` function, but this asserts for my all the time. Which is to be expected according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/48752995/85539 (this function works only for touch events coming from the touchbar, but not from the trackpad).

I couldn't find any other methods that look promising.

Comment: The answer to the linked questions says `-locationInView:` does not work for a touch bar. What is the assertion error?

Comment: The link to the `-locationInView:` might indeed be a different topic, now that I reread it. When I use this function with event from the touch pad (not the touch bar), I get the following assertion: `Assertion failure in -[NSTouch locationInView:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/AppKit/AppKit-1561.20.106/AppKit.subproj/NSTouch.m:99`